# Configure Unity to work with Web api

Tags: c#, unity-container

Unity config newbie, I am trying to implement this in my project. However, I am stuck.

I receive the following error: The current type, System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

**ContainerClass**

```
public class ContainerBootstrapper
    {
        public static void ConfigureUnityContainer()
        {
            //simple registeration
            container.RegisterType<IProduct, ProductHelper>(); //maps interface to a concrete type

            System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new MyProjectControllerDependency(container));

        }

    }
```

**DependencyResolver**

```
public class MyProjectControllerDependency : IDependencyResolver
{
private IUnityContainer _container;

public MyProjectControllerDependency(IUnityContainer container)
{
    this._container = container;
}

public object GetService(Type serviceType)
{
    return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
}

public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
{
    return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IProduct _iproduct;

    public ProductController(IProduct product)
    {
        this._iproduct = product;
    }
 //controller methods
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface IProduct
{
    List<ProductViewModel> GetProductByBarcode(string value);
    string GetProductPrice(string value);
}
```

**Helper**

```
public class ProductHelper : IProduct
    {
        //private readonly IProduct _iproduct;

        //public ProductHelper(IProduct iproduct)
        //{
        //    this._iproduct = iproduct;
        //}

        public List<ProductViewModel> GetProductByBarcode(string value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string GetProductPrice(string value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

I don't understand, what I am missing? Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you using Unity.Mvc?

Comment: I installed unity via nuget, I am not sure. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: For MVC and WebAPI project, Unity.MVC is required. You won't even need to create custom DependencyResolver. Install Unity.Mvc and look for examples in google. It's easy to configure and plug-in.

Comment: I will try this, and get back to you

Comment: This is what I needed, much simpler. post it as an answer. But I only need to use it for WebAPI project. I installed unity for webapi and that did the trick, as you mention. It does not need a custom dependency resolver

Comment: I am glad that it helped you to resolve the issue. I just posted by answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ASP.NET MVC and WebApi projects using only Unity is not sufficient. For these projects you also need to install `Unity.MVC` from nuget.

This is provides out of the box ready to use classes. You just need to register the dependencies in the UnityContainer and done.

Once you install `Unity.MVC`, it creates classes `UnityMvcActivator` and `UnityConfig`. `UnityConfig` class has implementation of initializing UnityContainer. All you need to do it register dependencies in `RegisterTypes` method.

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<IBaseClass, BaseClass>(); // Registering types
    container.LoadConfiguration();
}
```

You don't need to create any custom type or implementation unless and until you have completely different requirement.

This should help you resolve your issue.

Comment: I will accept this as it made me realise i need to implement unity for web api not not mvc for my purposes as I am only using web api.